# Where am I going wrong with finding eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Simple example, but I am having the same issues with all of the problems I attempt.

$$A=
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    6 & 3 \\
    2 & 7\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I get eigenvalues 4 and 9 for this (no problem here).

In order to get the eigenvectors I subtract A from I2*eigenvalue

This yields
$$E_{4}=
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & -3 \\
    -2 & -3\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$RREF(E_{4}) =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 1.5 \\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I know that I am supposed to get span $$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    3 \\
    -2 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

But to me this seems to be span $$
 \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 \\
    0 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

My thinking is $V_{1}*0+V_{2}*1.5 = 0 --> V_{2} = 0, and $ $V_{1}$ = 1. I know I am making a silly mistake but I can't figure it out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A-4I=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $A-9I=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & 3 \\ 2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$. It is these matrices that you should row reduce. (You could do $4I-A$ if you wanted, but that would be $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -3 \\ -2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$, which isn't what you have.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I have: 
$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -3 \\ -2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$ 
and I row reduce to 
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3/2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

I then get v1 + 3/2 v2 = 0.
v1 = -3/2v2

and v2 = 1. 
I think the problem I am having is definitely happening in this solving stage, where I am multiplying by a V vector and setting them equal to zero.

Comment: @user240352 The vector you have found is correct--it is proportional to the one in your solution, and so both are eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue.